# Concrete5 - Save array to DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, concrete5, concrete

I created block wchich you can add in it dynamically a multiple names. When I cick save, and return to the block editing, I dont see my new added names. I think that is problem with save to database. Please can someone help me with it?

Here is my code:

controller.php:

```
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

Loader::block('library_file');

class MultipleBlockController extends BlockController {
    protected $btName = 'Multiply TEST';
    protected $btDescription = 'Multiple add. TEST';
    protected $btTable = 'btDCMultiple';

    protected $btInterfaceWidth = "700";
    protected $btInterfaceHeight = "450";
}
```

db.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema version="0.3">
    <table name="btDCMultiple">

        <field name="bID" type="I">

            <key />
            <unsigned />

        </field>

        <field name="inputs" type="C" size="16"></field>

    </table>
</schema>
```

edit.php:

```
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

?>

<?php
$remove_row_icon = '<img src="'.ASSETS_URL_IMAGES.'/icons/remove_minus.png" class="remove_row" height="14" width="14" >';
$add_row_icon  = '<img src="'.ASSETS_URL_IMAGES.'/icons/add_small.png" class="add_row" height="14" width="14" >';
?>

<!-- Zakladki -->
<ul id="ccm-autonav-tabs" class="ccm-dialog-tabs">
    <li class="ccm-nav-active"><a id="ccm-autonav-tab-add" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php   echo t('Edit')?></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Odstep konfiguracja -->
<div style="padding: 10px">

    <div class="ccm-autonavPane" id="ccm-autonavPane-add">

        <h2>debug</h2>

        <table>
        <tr><td><?php echo 'Name';?></td><td></td></tr>
        <?php

            foreach($inputs as $a_name) { ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="10"  name="inputs"   value="<?php  echo $a_name ?>" ></td>
            <td><?php echo $add_row_icon; echo (' '); echo $remove_row_icon;?></td>
            </tr>  
    <?php   }   ?>
</table>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add_row').live('click',function(){
    var copy_of_row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(copy_of_row).find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(copy_of_row);
  });

  $('.remove_row').live('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

});
</script>
```

view.php:

```
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

?>

<div>

    <?php echo $inputs ?>

</div>
```

Another question: How can I load an array from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code:

1. if your field inputs is going to repeat itself, you need to add
   brackets [] to its name so it becomes `name="inpust[]"`
2. In your database table, the field bID contains the block ID and it's a key
       field meaning only one row in your db can have that value. In your
       case, if you have 3 inputs, you will have 3 rows with the same bID
       which is impossible.

I suggest you look at the core slideshow block for an example of saving multiple values for one block by using 2 separate tables.

Concerning your other question once you load the database helper you can do

```
$rows = $db->getArray($sql,$vals);
```

Where $rows will contain your array of values, $sql is your sql call (SELECT * FROM whatever_table...) and $vals (optional) contains filtering values to use in your sql.